# Some devices can not read NfcA card

Tags: android, nfc

I try read nfc tags from NfcA card:

Activity:

```
public class NfcActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String[][] techList = new String[][]{
            new String[]{
                    NfcA.class.getName(),
                    NfcB.class.getName(),
                    NfcF.class.getName(),
                    NfcV.class.getName(),
                    IsoDep.class.getName(),
                    MifareClassic.class.getName(),
                    MifareUltralight.class.getName(), Ndef.class.getName()
            }
    };

    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private NfcAdapter mAdapterNFC;

    private static final IntentFilter[] INTENT_FILTERS = {new IntentFilter((NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED))};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        mAdapterNFC = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapterNFC.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, INTENT_FILTERS, techList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mAdapterNFC.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
...
 <activity android:name=".NfcActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/filter_nfc" />
        </activity>
```

filter_nfc:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

When I put the card on the phone - I handle `Intent` in `onNewIntent` method. But with some device I have strange behavior - `onNewIntent` method not rtigered. I try explain:

Samsung J7 2016 and S8:

1. I put the card with NfcA tag - I handle `Intent` in `onNewIntent` method
2. I put the card with NfcA+IsoDep tag - I handle `Intent` in `onNewIntent` method

All work fine. But with Samsung A5 2016(two identical devices):

1. I put the card with NfcA tag - I **NOT** handle `Intent` in `onNewIntent` method
2. I put the card with NfcA+IsoDep tag - I handle `Intent` in `onNewIntent` method

I download NFC Rider app from google play and this app has same behavior as my program - **Samsung J7 2016 and S8** - can read all cards and `onNewIntent` method is work and **Samsung A5 2016** - can read only card with 2 tags(NfcA+IsoDep)

I download **TagInfo NXP** from google play - and this app can read **all cards** on **all devices**.

Based on this, I draw conclusions that the device is working and hcan work with these cards. but I can not understand what I'm missing so that in my program this also worked. And why in other programs the same behavior like my program.

Comment: https://github.com/jcgharvey/NfcA/blob/master/src/com/example/hopcardtrial/MainActivity.java may be helpful to you

Comment: @ Bhupat Bheda I used this example